# MDX for age range

Tags: range, mdx

I have a following MDX query:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[PARTICIPANT ID]} ON columns,
{[GENDER].[Female Gender]} ON rows
FROM [Dystonia DS]
```

I have a dimension called `AGE IN YEARS` and I want to filter `PARTICIPANT ID` using age range i.e `PARTICIPANT ID`s between AGE 20 to 54 etc.

I got solution for date range on this forum but unable to make it for age range by referring date range MDX.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't "Age in years" be a measure if you want to use it to perform calculation (or filtering) on?

Comment: I can put AGE IN YEARS as another measure along with PARTICIPANT ID if filtering is not possible using AGE IN YEARS as a dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is really another dimension, and you don't want to display it, can't you just add it to the WHERE clause?

```
SELECT {[Measures].[PARTICIPANT ID]} ON columns,
{[GENDER].[Female Gender]} ON rows
FROM [Dystonia DS]
WHERE {[Age Range].&[20]:[Age Range].&[54]}
```

And if you need to see it, add it to the tuple in the ROWS dimension.

```
SELECT {[Measures].[PARTICIPANT ID]} ON columns,
([GENDER].[Female Gender],
{[Age Range].&[20]:[Age Range].&[54]}) ON rows
FROM [Dystonia DS]
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much! It worked.
I really love this forume!